# Best Practice way of converting from one type to another in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have 2 interfaces:

```
interface Person{
    name: string;
}

interface Employee extends Person{
    employeeId: string;
}
```

and I want to convert a Person to en Employee:

```
function employPerson(person: Person, id: string): Employee
```

What is the best approach?

I think that the standard way of doing this is:

```
function employPerson(person: Person, id: string): Employee{
    const employee = person as Employee

    employee.employeeId = id;

    return employee;
}
```

which works but this also works:

```
function employPerson(person: Person, id: string): Employee{
    const employee = person as Employee

    return employee;
}
```

which is obviously not right.

I like this approach:

```
function employPerson(person: Person, id: string): Employee{
    return {
        ...person,
        employeeId: id
    };
}
```

This ensures that we have all the correct properties and if I change the `Employee` interface to add a new property the above code will correctly error. The problem with this is that I am returning a different object - it's a clone.

How do I add a property to an existing object whilst still using full type safety?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `Object.assign`?

```
function employPerson(person: Person, id: string): Employee {
    return Object.assign(person, {
        employeeId: id
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that seems to work but I think that is ES6. I am looking for a solution that works in ES5.
Thanks

Comment: @Roaders - that should still work for ES5 because TypeScript will "down" compile your code to whatever you target.

Comment: Actually it very rarely does that. TS doesn't do polyfills. To use a Map for example you need to use ES6. I am 90% sure that's the case for Object.assign as well.

Comment: `employee.employeeId = id` is faster than `Object.assign(person, { employeeId: id })` though. Is there really no way to do `employee.employeeId = id` and make TS _know_ that the type changed?

Answer (score 2):

```
  const employeePerson = (person: Person, id: string) => {
    const employee: Employee = {...person, id }
    return employee
  }
```

Even not necessary a function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is to discard the type safety.  This isn't inherently bad (just most times it is bad).  Here, in a "conversion" function, it *might* be a reasonable thing to do. Here's one example:

```
function convertPersonToEmployee(person: Person, id: string): Employee {
    const result = person as any; // type-cast to any
    result.employeeId = id;
    return result as Employee;
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQG8CwAUMiciHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNxEC+RRoksiKAUQoAHADZYAnhBQQAHpBAATDGkw4CxUhBHipEAJKLa9RiFYcuhGAFcQCMMBzIEOAG7Qw6KNhAAVLEJiktIAFMJqILRePgA0yMBGdAzMAJS0gbrSyBqkzjj0yFAQGNaiYMgAvMjh3k5wKnAgEizIAPStyGAS4QC0CPXlYFjIjRJEuUUlZQB02kF6hpXximyaJEVg1lAghcWl5fXIGcEQq5yERC4gBeFYYihREQDaALpLT+OkuGSUNMgARABlSj-UjsGKfEjfchUWj-ACComASFB4Mh2R+sIBACEsAAjUEkNGEF6rS75A5IpAACWARUUSyu7igngi-mOehC1Qgd1EECeAEYXnEAOwi5ApVZXbB86biJghAAGiOREFp9MqFSqABJcAApQEAeQActMTMxgDAJCE4FS1XSIIoUuxFZLLDAsFBkCE+eVgEsAAwtf0AHm5vIgcogZjAAAtgwBqBMpbLo6VYWXypW3e5PXXAdhvLU6-VG03msyW605vlPYAvZ2us5EIA)

However, unless you have actual data showing creation of a new object to be a performance issue, or data showing that you have existing code relying on modification of the function parameters, there are strong reasons to AVOID this type of in-place modification, as it makes maintenance (changing stuff) more difficult.

That said, the above *does* work.